# How to send a global message?

Tags: discord.js

I'm wanting to send a message (in a way as a global announcement to all servers) about important information regarding the bot. *In this instance, regarding unplanned downtime.*

---

`guild.channels.find(t => t.name == 'general').send` I think.. is correct coding to find a text-channel with the name #general. (I want to add 'announcements' / 'lounge') as a back-up if #general isn't an option.

I have no clue where to start on coding up this command. 
Any help would be appreciated.

---

**BELOW YOU CAN FIND A SEMI-TEMPLATE / IDEA OF WHAT I WANT?**

*some parts of the code are chopped out, this is no way effects below.*

```
exports.exec = async (Peepo, message, args) => {  

    // Fires Error message that the command wasn't ran correctly.
    if (args.length < 1) {
    return message.channel.send({embed: {
     color: 0,
     description: `${message.author} add some words.`
  }
});
}
    // Fires Error message that the command wasn't ran correctly.


// FETCH CHANNELS TO SEND ANNOUNCEMENT TO


      message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          color: 0,
          title: ` ANNOUNCEMENT`,
          description: `${guild.name}{`,
          footer: {
          text: "${guild.name} this is an official message from the creator of this bot."

};

/* * * * */
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `Guild.defaultChannel` Note: This is deprecated and may be removed in other versions

Comment: I'm on `11.4.2 for Discord JS` I don't believe it works anymore sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to message the guild owner.

```
client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
     client.users.get(guild.ownerID).send("Important announcement!");
});
```

Every guild has an owner, so there's no worry about a server renaming their #general channel.

Comment: This is actually a really smart and unique way of doing it. Many thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a basic forEach loop that will send a message to the general channel of every server - do note it will not send if the guild doesn't have a #general

```
client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
    guild.channels.find(t => t.name == 'general').send('Some important announcement to all guilds!');
})
```